# AngularJs autocomplete almost working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Building a small search app using Elasticsearch and AngularJS, nearly have autocomplete working using the [AngularJS](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) Bootstrap typeahead, but I'm having trouble displaying the actual suggestions returned by ES.

I have this promise that is returning the results from ES

```
    this.getSuggestions = function(query) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    esClient.search({
      index: 'autocomplete',
      body: {
        "query": {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "autocomplete_field": {
            "query": query,
            "max_expansions": 10
            }
          }
        },
        "size": 5,
        "from": 0,
        "_source": ["autocomplete_field"]
      }
    }).then(function(es_return) {
      deferred.resolve(es_return);
    }, function(error) {
      deferred.reject(error);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  };
```

This is the HTML with AngularJS UI Bootstrap stuff

```
<input type="text" name="q" ng-model="searchTerms" placeholder="Search" class="form-control input-lg" uib-typeahead="query for query in getSuggestions($viewValue)" typeahead-on-select="search($item)" typeahead-popup-template-url="customPopupTemplate.html" auto-focus>
```

And this is the getSuggestions function in the controller

```
    //get suggestions
  $scope.getSuggestions = function(query) {
  $scope.isSearching = true;
  return searchService.getSuggestions(query).then(function(es_return){
    var phrases = es_return.hits.hits;
    console.log(phrases);
    if (phrases) {
      return $scope.autocomplete.suggestions = phrases;
    };
    $scope.isSearching = false;
    });
};
```

I'm getting 5 suggestions in the dropdown, but I'm not accessing the actual value... what I get is this, repeated 5 times

```
[object Object]
```

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with this line

```
var phrases = es_return.hits.hits;
```

My console.log outputs this

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

I'm not quite sure how to access the value of **"autocomplete_field"** in the `_source` object of the ES results?

**UPDATE** The template for the dropdown menu is

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="listbox">
    <li ng-repeat="match in matches track by $index" ng-class="{active: isActive($index) }"
      ng-mouseenter="selectActive($index)" ng-click="selectMatch($index)" role="option" id="{{::match.id}}">
      <div uib-typeahead-match index="$index" match="match" query="query" template-url="templateUrl"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE 2** and here an example json response

```
    {
   "took": 5,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": 2.5897822,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "autocomplete",
            "_type": "suggestions",
            "_id": "229",
            "_score": 2.5897822,
            "_source": {
               "autocomplete_field": "fast and furious"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "autocomplete",
            "_type": "suggestions",
            "_id": "230",
            "_score": 2.5897822,
            "_source": {
               "autocomplete_field": "die hard"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "autocomplete",
            "_type": "suggestions",
            "_id": "107",
            "_score": 1.7686365,
            "_source": {
               "autocomplete_field": "the bourne identity"
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: What does your template look like?

Comment: Probably should be `uib-typeahead="query as query.title for query in getSuggestions($viewValue)"` (Where `title` supposed to be the display property, but since you haven't provided the JSON so I can only guess the correct property name)

Comment: @MikeRobinson sorry about the delay, please take a look at UPDATE above, has the dropdown template

Comment: @AlonEitan sorry about the delay, added JSON in UPDATE 2 above, thanks

Comment: @user3125823 Try `uib-typeahead="query as query._source.autocomplete_field for query in getSuggestions($viewValue)"`

Comment: @AlonEitan that fixed it! Thank so much. If you put it in an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: @user3125823 Thanks! Added it as answer

Comment: @AlonEitan is there a more "elegant" way of accessing the value or is this it - either way, thanks again!

Comment: @user3125823 AFAIK it's the only way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing the structure of your JSON, I can tell that you need to change the `uib-typeahead` attribute to this:

```
uib-typeahead="query as query._source.autocomplete_field for query in getSuggestions($viewValue)"
```